# Why using `chan struct{}` when wait something done not `chan interface{}`?

Tags: go, channel

In golang, when we need to wait for something to finish, we will use a channel.

example:

```
done := make(chan struct{})
go func() {
    // ...
    close(done)
}()
<-done
```

But, in other way, `chan interface{}` also works in this case.

So, what's the difference between `chan struct{}` and `chan interface{}`?

Example2:

```
done := make(chan struct{})
go func() {
    // ...
    done <- struct{}{}
}()
<- done
```

In other case, if don't close channel in goroutine instead of send object to it.

There will create an object in goroutine, but if using `chan interface{}`, can be send `nil` object to channel.

Is it better to use `chan struct{}`?

Answer (score 47):

In your example of a 'done' channel, functionally speaking, the channel can be of literally any type, since no data is actually sent, and the channel is just used as a signaling mechanism. But in the interest of memory utilization, `struct{}` is the smallest data type available in Go, since it contains literally nothing, so no allocation necessary, which is why it's typically used in such scenarios.

Answer (score 8):

The empty struct `struct {}` requires no memory. So if you have a channel with a large capacity you can save a few bytes by switching from `make(chan bool, 1<<16)` to `make(struct {}, 1<<16)`. Using interface {} requires more space and is really strange here.

For an unbuffered done channel I think using struct {} is *wrong* as it is unclear. Using a simple `chan bool` is much more sensible. Using interface {} is completely wrong: It probably uses more space and is even less clear than struct {}.

Comment: I'm confused by your last paragraph. In what sense is `struct{}` wrong for an unbuffered done channel? And how is `chan bool` more sensible? `chan bool` implies that you'll be sending true or false values over the channel, which is not true, so it seems "wrong" to me. But I'm curious to know your reasoning.

Comment: @Flimzy Done channels in the stdlib are chan bool and even if you never send false or not even send anything but just close the channel it just is more natural to use a chan bool. E.g. the chan struct{} also does not convey that you never intend to send anything. And strcut {} is more to type and more to read and especially a rare language construct with special semantics as a all instances of struct{} may share the same memory location. Less common, more complicated, more characters, less clear ==> wrong.

Comment: "Done channels in the stdlib are chan bool" -- this is not a universally true statement. There are many examples of `chan struct{}` for done channels in the stdlib.  But thank you for your explanation.